# questions about vectors of string and ofstream objects

Tags: c++, vector

I define a string object vectors and ofstream object vectors without initializing them,
then I initialize them similar to giving values to arrays, the following is my code,

```
std::vector<std::ofstream> myFiles;
std::vector<std::string> myFileNames;
int tmp[4];

for(int k=0; k<3; k++)
{   
    tmp[k] = myID[k] + '0';
    myFileNames[k] = "file";
    myFileNames[k] += tmp[k];
    myFileNames[k] += " .csv ";

    std::cout<< "Opening file:" << myFileNames[k] << std::endl;
    myFiles[k].open (myFileNames[k].c_str());
    myFiles[k]<< "t,x,y";<<std::endl;
}
```

there's no errors when i compile it,however, when i run it, it said vector subscript out of range, I'm not sure whether it's because I don't initialize the vector with a fixed number of subscript, could anyone help me with how to define a vector of fixed number of string and ofstream objects, in my case, both are 3 of them, any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The vector is *empty* when you create it. You need to *add* elements to it. You can do that by calling `push_back/emplace_back` to add them one by one, or by calling `resize` to give it the final size in one shot. I would opt for `emplace_back` in this case.

```
myFileNames.emplace_back("file");
myFilenames.back() += tmp[k];
myFilenames.back() += ".csv";
```

Comment: resize seems to only work with int, however I still want to refer to the elements like myFileNames[0],[1],... and myFiles[0],[1],... from your methods I can't do that!

Comment: @user2647095: Resize should work with basically any type that can be inserted into a vector, one way or another (what compiler/version are you using? what is the error? You need C++11 to be able to work with a `vector<ofstream>`) Also note that the mechanism used for insertion does not affect how you refer to the elements after, you can substitute `myFilenames.back()` with `myFilenames[N]` for the appropriate `N` at each time.

Comment: I use vs 2008, so maybe I should define four file objects and their name string objects respectively, thank you.

Comment: I have another question, if I use resize for thr string vector, should it be myFileNames.resize(new std::string,4)?

Comment: @user2647095: You should really look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)... The first argument is the new size, the second argument [optional] is the value that the new elements if any will take. If the vector holds `std::string`, that will be a `std::string` (not a `std::string*`)

Comment: I put myFileNames.resize(std::vector<std::string>::size_type 4); but it stills says missing type specifier int assumed, sorry if i asked so stupid question,'cause i'm new to C++

Comment: @user2647095: You really need to go over the basics of the syntax in a tutorial. The call would be `myFilenames.resize(4)`. The `4` will be converted to the *type* `std::vector<std::string>::size_type` internally (that type is really `std::size_t`). But if you have problems understanding the documentation of `resize`, then you really need to go back to basics. Find a good book or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try using insert instead of the [] operator. According to the C++ page, the [] operator checks the bounds and the default constructor creates a empty vector (size 0) which is where you're getting the exception

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to start with 3 default-constructed values in your vector, do this:

```
std::vector<std::ofstream> myFiles(3);
std::vector<std::string> myFileNames(3);
```

Otherwise, use `push_back` or `resize` methods.